# Changing String to Date and Time in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of character class strings.

[image]

I want to covert this to Sys.time() format. How can I do that?
When I use the `as.POSIXct(z,format= "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`
 I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I don't want this to convert to NAs. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Kindly use

```
strptime("2014-06-05 15:33:55 IST","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="Asia/Kolkata")
```

For your problem

```
data$time <- strptime(data$time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="Asia/Kolkata")
class(data$time)
```

It should be of type POSIXlt

Comment: It is working for single string. But when I use this formula in a loop or I pass a vector to the strptime function. I get warnings and every string is converted to 23. Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, 1, value = list(sec = 23, min = 45L,  :
  provided 11 variables to replace 1 variables
2: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, 1, value = list(sec = 23, min = 45L,  :
  provided 11 variables to replace 1 variables
3: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, 1, value = list(sec = 23, min = 45L,  :
  provided 11 variables to replace 1 variables

Comment: Have just updated my answer for your data frame variable..I am assuming your data is called data and time is the feature name.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for the benefit of those Googling this problem, I had a similar problem recently when using rbind.fill.  I discovered that one of my dates was in European format, 31/1/2017 instead of 1/31/2017 like all the others.  It was causing R to blank out the entire column after performing rbind.fill.  Fixing the date fixed the issue.

Hope this helps someone, I spent hours trying to figure out why this was happening.  R is really picky sometimes.